# How do I fix the R code error: 'factors are not allowed'?

Tags: r

I have a data set of around 12 columns and 40,000 rows and I have created a table of just one of the columns called `table7`. I am trying to find the bottom 10% of this row using the following code and keep getting the 'factors are not allowed' error. If anyone could possible help me resolve the issue that would be great!

```
perform_data <- data.table(read.csv(file = 'ns_project_performance_432_SOWs.csv')) 

table7 <- perform_data[project_id == 7] 

v_ead <- quantile(table7[ ,pv_ead_reduction], 0.9)
```

Comment: I imagine you are using `quantile` on a field that is not formatted as a numeric vector. Please refer to the help page of the function: `?quantile`. Also, would you be able to provide a sample of your data so that we can better assist you?

Comment: I am assuming the data is a numeric vector, but am unsure how to check. This is what table_7 looks like except there are 4,000 data pts:    
  "99,342,542,289.52", "99,374,500,267.23", "99,383,177,167.85", 
    "99,490,390,842.63", "99,535,557,603.84", "99,536,660,885.94", 
    "99,596,112,745.84", "99,736,591,496.01", "99,744,738,856.71", 
    "99,753,043,493.18", "99,761,111,712.26", "99,782,032,251.78", 
    "99,896,376,373.70", "99,903,662,490.68"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-432L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001f797361ef0>)